# Show local storage on page load/refresh in OL

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have been trying to create a To Do list and keep running into different problems. Right now I am trying to pull from the array from local storage, so when I refresh the browser it will display the To Do list. I have tried I know I need to do something along the lines of

```
localStorage.getItem
```

but I am not sure how to go about doing so. I think I need to place it into a different function and then call that different function at the end of my JavaScript. I also think I need to use a for loop for this. I think I may need to redo my current JavaScript but am not sure where to go from here.

JavaScript

```
var masterList = [];

function addToList(){
  var task = document.getElementById('todoInput').value;
  var entry = document.createElement('li'); //2
  var list = document.getElementById('orderedList'); //2
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task)); //2
  list.appendChild(entry); //2

  masterList.push(task);

  localStorage.setItem('masterList', JSON.stringify(masterList));

  console.log(task);
  console.log(masterList);
  clearInput();
 }

function clearInput() {
    todoInput.value = "";
}

console.log((localStorage.getItem('masterList')));
```

HTML

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

  <h1>To Do List:<h1>

    <input id="todoInput" type="text">
    <button type="button" onclick="addToList()">Add Item</button>
    <ol id='orderedList'></ol>

<script src="todo.js"></script>

</body>
```

CSS

```
ol li {
  background: lightgray;
  text-align: left;
}

ol li:nth-child(odd){
  background: lightblue;
  text-align: left
  text: 10%;
}

input[type=text]{
  width: 20%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-align: center;
}

h1{
  text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call a function on document load, which will get the `todo` list from `localStorage`. If it doesn't exist, the `masterList` will become an empty array and will be ready to store `todos` inside.

**Note**: Check if it works, because due to the cors blockage on SO I'm unable to test it.

```js
var masterList;

window.onload = function(){
  masterList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('masterList')); //get data from storage
  if (masterList !== null) { //if data exist (todos are in storage)
    masterList.forEach(function(v){ //append each element into the dom
      var task = v;
      var entry = document.createElement('li'); //2
      var list = document.getElementById('orderedList'); //2
      entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task)); //2
      list.appendChild(entry); //2
    })
  } else { //if nothing exist in storage, keep todos array empty
    masterList = [];
  }
}

function addToList(){
  var task = document.getElementById('todoInput').value;
  var entry = document.createElement('li'); //2
  var list = document.getElementById('orderedList'); //2
  entry.appendChild(document.createTextNode(task)); //2
  list.appendChild(entry); //2

  masterList.push(task);

  localStorage.setItem('masterList', JSON.stringify(masterList));

  console.log(task);
  console.log(masterList);
  clearInput();
 }

function clearInput() {
    todoInput.value = "";
}
```

Comment: @bemon It's not really helpful reply, why doesn't it work? Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: I am sorry, did not mean to be unhelpful with the reply. I did not show any errors when I changed my code and ran it, it just simply did not do anything different than before. It still shows it all in the console, but nothing occurred on screen and I did not see any errors show up in the console or anywhere.

Comment: It does work now, I will be going through to see what does what exactly within the code. Thank you so much for your help and assistance!

Comment: @bemon I've added description to every step.

Comment: thank you so much, I greatly appreciate the help and description...thank you thank you thank you!